# Spark otherwise() is always being evaluated

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine I have the following code:

```
val option: Option[String] = ??? // May be some or none
val validation: Boolean = ??? // May be true or false

val df = ??? // load data
```

Now I want to add two new columns:

- The first one is a boolean-based column
- The second one is based on a when-otherwise clause. When the previous
  column is true, I just put a `lit(3)` value. When it is false, I call
  a function that should throw an exception when a option value does
  not exist:

  ```
  def dealWithOtherwise(maybeString: Option[String]): Column = {
     maybeString match {
       case Some(default) => lit(default)
       case None => throw new Exception()
     }
  }

  df
   .withColumn("validationIsOk", validation)
   .withColumn("field",
      when(col("validationIsOk"), lit(3)).otherwise(dealWithOtherwise(option))
   )
  ```

I want to throw an exception just when `option = None`  and `validation = false`. However, I'm getting the Exception thrown when validation is true and default option is None. It is like otherwise function is always being executed for each row, no matter the condition in the when clause.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confuse two different things - evaluation of execution plan (this is what happens here) and evaluation of physical plan on actual data (which doesn't happen here). Execution plan has to be always evaluated, otherwise Spark wouldn't know how to generate corresponding code. From the other hand, different branches of evaluation can be either pruned from the plan or skipped during execution (using standard control flow).

In your case plan is simply invalid, as `None` cannot be used as literal. This doesn't imply anything about thew way in which such plan is evaluated on actual data (which in practice might, or might not short circuit, depending on the expression used).

In fact you can easily check that optimized plan for trivially true or false `CASE WHEN` removes other branch completely in such simple cases

```scala
spark.range(1).select(when(lit(true), 1).otherwise(2) as "x").explain(true)
```

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Project [CASE WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS x#10]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
x: int
Project [CASE WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS x#10]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [1 AS x#10]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [1 AS x#10]
+- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=8)
```

```scala
spark.range(1).select(when(lit(false), 1).otherwise(2) as "x").explain(true)
```

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Project [CASE WHEN false THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS x#14]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
x: int
Project [CASE WHEN false THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS x#14]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [2 AS x#14]
+- Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=Some(8))

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [2 AS x#14]
+- *(1) Range (0, 1, step=1, splits=8)
```

However, you shouldn't extrapolate this - some modes of execution (certain variants of UDFs in particular), cannot be optimized this way.

Please refer to [`SimplifyConditionals` source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c16fae5c1369387d3730ce9851cb5e6fbd229c7/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/expressions.scala#L452-L510) for details.

Comment: Everything I said here stays valid - evaluation of execution plan != evaluation of the generated code on the actual data. Your code doesn't even reach the point where something is "being executed for each row".